# Angularjs SignalR connection not working

Tags: angularjs, signalr

For some reason this should work. Feels like I am missing something but I am not sure.  I can return the data on jquery side. On the Angularjs side I can send to server but the client does not seem to iniitate. I also tested the connection in angularjs side and it seem to initate. For some reason I am not seeing the data returned like the jquery file. Suggestions please.

Jquery works on client

```js
   $(function () {
        $.connection.hub.start()
            .done(function () {
                console.log('SignalR connected, connection id = ' + $.connection.hub.id);
                console.log('Username = ' + '001');
                $.connection.messageHub.server.connectToMessageHub('001');
            })
            .fail(function (data) {
                console.log('SignalR failed to connect: ' + data);
            });
 
        $.connection.messageHub.client.reloadData = function (jsonObject) {
          console.log("data invokes called");
          console.log('get data=', jsonObject);
    
        };
     
    });
        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () { // initiate connection
      });
    });
```

AngularJS does not work. I can send message to server but the client does not seem to invoke or initiate.

```js
    $scope.dataHub = null;
   $scope.dataHub = $.connection.messageHub;

        $.connection.hub.start(); // starts hub
// never makes it after start.
        $scope.dataHub.client.reloadData = function (message) {
            var newMessage = 'name' + ' says: ' + message;
            console.log('test', message);
 
            $scope.AllItems.push(newMessage);
            $scope.$apply();
        };
```

```
   $.connection.hub.logging = true;
    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
        console.log('Your Hub started Sucessfully.');
    });

    $scope.dataHub = function () {

        $scope.hub = $.connection.alertUser;

        $scope.notify = function () {
            console.log('loaded');
            $scope.hub.client.reloaddata = function (name) {
                console.log('loaded=', name);

                $scope.$apply(function () {
                    $scope.AllItems.push(name);
                });
            }
            $.connection.hub.start();
        }
        $scope.notify();





    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am not sure that you provided correct hub url or not, You can refer below code.
>   I have added below code in my app.config and it is woking fine for me please check at your en

```
// create the module and name it signalRApp
var signalRApp = angular.module('signalRApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngMaterial', 'ngAnimate', 'timer']);
// configure our routes

$.connection.hub.url = 'http://localhost:44444/signalr';

hub = $.connection;

signalRApp.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
         // route for the home page
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'app/template/index.html',
            controller: 'AlertCtrl'
        });


    $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
});
// create the controller and inject Angular's $scope
//This should be your bootstraper of main controller of your application.
signalRApp.controller('mainController', function ($scope,$rootScope,$timeout) {
    // create a message to display in our view
    $rootScope.enableLoadingImage = false;
    // Pass  your hub name
    $rootScope.hub = hub.messageHub;

    $rootScope.Message = [];
    $scope.uniqueIds=[];

    $rootScope.hub.client.reloaddata  = function (item) {


        console.log('we got pointer here!!')

    }



});
```

> Let me know if you can do that other wise i will share one sample
>   project around it.

Comment: The connection is successful. After I post the data. I cannot get anything on the return. I added console and it never makes it pass the client.reloaddata. so frustrating. It should work but does not. I have the Signalr url just cannot get pass the client.  I added snipplet above what I tried.

Comment: @/sevensnake77787 updated answer, Let me know if you can do that other wise i will share one sample project around it.